# Given x or y can and the correlation coefficient can you approximate the other?

Tags: correlation, approximation

Give x or y can and the correlation coefficient can you approximate the other?

The definition of correlation coefficient is:

$$r=\frac{\sum(x_i-\bar{x})(y_i-\bar{y})}{\sqrt{\sum(x_i-\bar{x})^2(y_i-\bar{y})^2}}$$

So you clearly cannot calculate the mean of x or y or the points. Is there a way to approximate the mean of x or y given the correlation coefficient and the other variable? Even approximating the mean of the other would be very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

No. The correlation tells you absolutely nothing about the means of the variables.

Consider 3 data sets

```
x = (1, 2, 3)
y = (1, 1, 3)

x = (1001, 1002, 1003)
y = (1, 1, 3)

x = (1, 2, 3)
y = (1001, 1001, 1003)
```

The correlation for all 3 is 0.866. The only thing correlation tells you is the slope of the line that fits the data. Shifting the data up by 1000 or to the right by 1000 doesn't change the slope.